Python scrape variations with multiple combinations for size and colour
I am trying to scrape the variants sizes and colour.
Here is the following scenario below:
Selected Colour:
-Mantis Green -Spool Yellow
Selected Size:
-6lb  -8lb  -10lb  -15lb  -20lb  -30lb
I need to scrape the title, price, and special price, with the following code below.
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class FishingRodsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ana_rods_detailed"
    allowed_domains = ["anacondastores.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.anacondastores.com/fishing/fishing-line/braid-line/shimano-kairiki-8-braid-line-150-metre-spool/BP90140299"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 2})

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('.pdp-title::text').get().strip()
        price = response.css('.product-info .price-was .amount::text').get().strip()
        club_price = response.css('.product-info .price-now .amount::text').get().strip()
        product_details = response.css('.product-details-list')
        base_url = "https://www.anacondastores.com"
        variant_style_pickers = response.css('.js-variant-style-picker')
        variant_size_pickers = response.css('.js-variant-size')
        style_data_urls = []
        for i, style_picker in enumerate(variant_style_pickers):
            style_data_url = style_picker.attrib.get('data-url')
            if i == 0 and style_data_url is None:
                for size_picker in variant_size_pickers:
                    size_data_url = size_picker.attrib.get('data-url')
                    if size_data_url is not None:
                        size_variant_url = base_url + size_data_url
                        # self.log("Size Variant: " + size_variant_url)
                    else:
                        self.log("Size data-url attribute is missing for a size picker.")
            else:
                if style_data_url is not None:
                    style_data_urls.append(base_url + style_data_url)
                    for size_picker in variant_size_pickers:
                        size_data_url = size_picker.attrib.get('data-url')
                        if size_data_url is not None:
                            size_variant_url = base_url + size_data_url
                            self.log("Size Variant: " + size_variant_url)
                else:
                    self.log("Style data-url attribute is missing for a style picker.")

Expected Result
-Mantis Green 6lb -Mantis Green 8lb -Mantis Green 10lb -Mantis Green 20lb -Mantis Green 30lb
-Spool Yellow 6lb -Spool Yellow 8lb -Spool Yellow 10lb -Spool Yellown 20lb -Spool Yellow 30lb

Can you show examples of what outputs are you getting, since we don't know the problem here we can't really help you.

Hi Onur, I need the following output title, price, sale price, https://i.imgur.com/y2giYTz.png the value of the following fields varies with the combination of colour and sizes.

Since you're new here, I wanted to say that you shouldn't use stackoverflow to make people write code for you. If you tried a code and it didn't work, you're free to come here and ask for help.

@onur I'm having troubles with this logic, I was able the fetch the first selected option variant and it's option on select level variants but not the second option on first level variant. Line 44 - Line 55, this is where I need help.

The data for this website is available in the loaded page so no need to use scrapy-splash. You need to check the network activity to find the url that is generated when you click on a color or size option. See below sample code:
import scrapy


class AnacondaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "anaconda"
    allowed_domains = ["www.anacondastores.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.anacondastores.com/fishing/fishing-line/braid-line/shimano-kairiki-8-braid-line-150-metre-spool/BP90140299-mantis-green"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # get all colors and scrape them
        color_urls = response.css(".js-variant-style-picker::attr(data-url)").getall()
        for url in color_urls:
            yield response.follow(url)

        # get all the sizes and scrape them
        size_codes = response.css(
            ".size-variant a::attr(data-variant-size-code)"
        ).getall()

        for code in size_codes:
            url = response.urljoin(code + "?version=7")
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_size)

    def parse_size(self, response):
        item = dict()

        item["title"] = response.css(
            "#productContentWrapper > div::attr(data-product-name)"
        ).get()
        item["price"] = response.css(
            "#productContentWrapper > div::attr(data-product-metric1)"
        ).get()
        item["sale_price"] = response.css(
            "#productContentWrapper > div::attr(data-product-price)"
        ).get()
        item["size"] = response.css(
            "#productContentWrapper > div::attr(data-product-dimension13)"
        ).get()

        yield item

